why does my Select query sometimes add a timestamp when running automated?
Fellow readers,
I am currently working on automating tests for a regression test set that i have built in Robot Framework and am running both locally and in a (Jenkins)CI/CD pipeline. I have a set that runs without issues localy, however, every once in a while it seems to act up when it runs during the automated deployment. And specifically on a set of 2 query's, that start with a Select query i listed below.
Normally these run fine. However sometimes test fails, because the select statement seems to add a timestamp in front of the result it returns. Both me, as the tester, and the lead developer can't seem to figure out why it would do that.
the Select query is as follows:
select MAX(id)
from sourcetable
where relatie=67989160 AND JAAR=2020 ;

that result is returned in a variable and then used in follow-up query's.
I am logging the result so that i can verify it, and it gives results like below when it fails:
202409172117296411019011100000018379531010000000183523000000000183774800000000183777000000000183771800000000183780580000000018378070000000001837800000000001837800000000001837875800000000183797600015031250135600000018352300008400000003307200048255559000000000839630513000000000839630334210200013530000001837748000290000000330000110190111019012411101901213381000135300000018377700007000000003314000011019010000000008308811019011550000000008308811019011761101901170492000135100000018377180001070000000000000000055200013510000001837805800021000000000000000006900001351000000183780700002344000000000000000002079262501351000000183780000028000000000000000001089210938135100000018378000002240000000000000000033832069920001351000000183787580002500000000000000000010810001342000000183797600001280000000333360001101901000000000832001101901155000000000832001101901148110190183411019011342000135300000018359800052020001354000000183530000201200013540000001835804800021410200013540000001835806000041020001354000000183585800028120001354000000183585800020420001340000000183798000208606553620480000000008000000000000000100000000102444096007024719674241056768616674768104857698222

While the expected result is just the id, which in this case would have been 98222.
Does anyone have a explanation as to why the query sometimes returns a way longer value then it should? Or how to make sure that it will only return the ID and not also (what seems like) a timestamp?
I did not have much luck googling this issue.
Thanks in advance!

This does not seems related to Robot Framework, https://robotframework.org/.

Have you considered that the sourcetable table might have unexpected data in the id field sometimes?

@Iterokun that might be possible, however, when i check after the test have failed, it shows a normal ID. It also should not be possible to have unexpected data as it is a primary key field with AutoIncrement etc

agree with @iterokun there looks like bad data in the ID field.  My guess (but would need far more context to confirm) would be that the data is being inserted in this table as part of the test and when the test fails is being rolled back, which would explain why you can not see it after the run..... I would be adding logging to every point where data is inserted into this table during your tests to figgure out where bad data is being introduced.

Hello, i am away from work right now, but the code doesnt roll anything back. Once inserted, it stays there thill the next run. Which is also confirmed by the fsct that, when i check manually, i do see a regular id for the testdata. Which is the previous id+1, as one would expect. Not what looks like the timestamp of insertion +(previous id +1). We use a separate, clean, environment for the automated tests.
